# THREE.js rendering difference between BufferGeometry and Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

The following THREE.js (r83 - latest) code works without error and renders correctly when *geom* is passed to *THREE.Points()* as defined below.

Passing *bufferGeometry* instead, which is just a conversion from *geom* using *.fromGeometry(geom)*, causes nothing to render.  No errors reported.

```
// "vertexshader"
varying vec3 vColor;

void main() 
{
    vColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_PointSize = 2.0;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}

// "fragmentshader"
uniform sampler2D texture;  
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() 
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, 1.0 );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
}
```

I use a dumb *THREE.js* rendering animation:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
...

geom.vertices.push(particle);
...

var customUniforms = 
{
    texture:   { type: "t", value: texture },
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
{
    uniforms:       customUniforms,
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
    opacity: .5,
    transparent: true, 
    alphaTest: 0.5,  
});

var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geom );

// Renders correctly if I pass in 'geom', does nothing if 'bufferGeometry'
cloud = new THREE.Points(bufferGeometry, material);
...
```

From what I have seen and read this should work.  It seems as if *.fromGeometry()* is failing in some way but no errors are reported.  Tested on Mac (Chrome, Safari) and Windows (Chrome).

There is scant documentation but it would appear to be a *THREE.js* problem related to indexing the geometry during the conversion (*bufferGeometry* reports itself as nonIndexed).